# Magento Multilanguages

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

currently I have a Magento website installed on http://www.mywebsite.com, I have about 150 products in the catalog and only one language: the english.

Now I need to install another language in my website, the german. But the german store will have only about 30 products in the catalog and its domain is http://www.mywebsite.de.

I never handled a situation like this, is it long and difficult? Can anyone give me some suggestions on how to proceed?

I think this is a classical scenario for a Magento developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not difficult i think, You need to create another store from manage store section, you should have complete idea about multi-store. for different domain.
after cnfiguring two store then you need to install german language pack from connect manager. then you have to select language from configuration->general->local section of admin section. then you have to import product for two different store english and german.

thanks

Comment: and for having the products in two languages I need to duplicate them and insert manually the text?

Answer (score 0):

1. download the language pack from **http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations** and then unpack it to your magento directory. When the system ask if the folder "app" will be replaced, click "yes to all"
2. Then go to System -> Configuration.
3. Click the Create Store View link on top right, and type these in store

Store: Main Store

Name: "Language name"

Code: any

Status: Enabled

Sort order is optional.

Here, you can also disable any store view by disabling its status.

Save, go back to System > Configuration. In Current Configuration Scope dropdown box, you now see there’s new store view. Click that link.
On Locale options tab on the left, uncheck the “use website” checkbox then change the locale to the name of the storeview you just recently created. Save.
**Now you can have your website in your selected language.**
You can do this step to configure other existing store views, too.

Enjoy!